# Using RestSharp to deserialise JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization, restsharp

I have the following JSON object being returned from an API call beyond my control:

```
{
  "GetBusinessGroupsRestResult": [
  {
    "BgId": 1,
    "NodeLevel": 1,
    "BusinessDescription": "Business Groups",
    "BusinessName": "Root",
    "nodegroupid": 2,
    "nodegroupname": "Root",
    "nodegroupdesc": "Root",
    "sorkkey": "Root",
    "Marked": 2
  },
  {
    "BgId": 2,
    "NodeLevel": 2,
    "BusinessDescription": "Business A",
    "BusinessName": "Business A",
    "ParentID": 1,
    "nodegroupid": 3,
    "nodegroupname": "Business A",
    "nodegroupdesc": "Business A",
    "sorkkey": "Business A",
    "Marked": 2
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

I have created the following class structure in an attempt to deserialise it into C# object instances:

```
public class GetBusinessGroupsRestResult
{
    public List<BusinessGroup> BusinessGroups { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessGroup
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "BgId")]
    public int BusinessGroupId { get; set; }

    public int NodeLevel { get; set; }
    public string BusinessDescription { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "ParentID")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "nodegroupid")]
    public int NodeGroupId { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "nodegroupname")]
    public string NodeGroupName { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "sorkkey")]
    public string SortKey { get; set; }

    public int Marked { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to deserialise it using [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki), specifying the RootElement as `GetBusinessGroupsRestResult`. When attempting the deserialisation using RestSharp's `IRestResponse<T> Execute<T>(RestRequest)`, I recieve the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'RestSharp.JsonArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.
```

I've managed to deserialise responses from this API that don't return lists before, for example:

```
{
  "AcquireSecurityTokenRestResult": {
    "SecurityToken": "SECURITY-TOKEN",
    "SessionLength": 600000,
    "APIVersion": "VERSION"
  }
}
```

With the following POCO:

```
public class AcquireSecurityTokenRestResult
{
    public string SecurityToken { get; set; }
    public int SessionLength { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "APIVersion")]
    public string ApiVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to make it work. The `Execute` part:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:3000/");
var request = new RestRequest("main", Method.GET);
var response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);
```

And the classes:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<BusinessGroup> GetBusinessGroupsRestResult { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessGroup
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "BgId")]
    public int BusinessGroupId { get; set; }

    public int NodeLevel { get; set; }
    public string BusinessDescription { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "ParentID")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "nodegroupid")]
    public int NodeGroupId { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "nodegroupname")]
    public string NodeGroupName { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "nodegroupdesc")]
    public string NodeGroupDesc { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "sorkkey")]
    public string SortKey { get; set; }

    public int Marked { get; set; }
}
```

Since the main response is an object which contains an array called `GetBusinessGroupsRestResult`, you need that in your root object as well.

You can basically fix your example by adding a `DeserializeAs` attribute to the `BusinessGroups` property in your `GetBusinessGroupsRestResult` class:

```
public class GetBusinessGroupsRestResult
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "GetBusinessGroupsRestResult")]
    public List<BusinessGroup> BusinessGroups { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It makes so much sense when you see the solution! Thank you! I should note that in my implementation I was creating the `RestRequest` with a wrapper function that set the `RootElement` property (e.g. here to `GetBusinessGroupsRestResult`) - for the other API calls like `AcquireSecurityTokenRest` this was required, but here it would cause deserialisation to fail and I had to set `RootElement` to `null` in order for the `[DeserializeAs(Name = "GetBusinessGroupsRestResult")]` annotation to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

More than an answer, piece of advice. Instead of using RESTSharp why don't you use Json.NET?

I ran into issues with RESTSharp that works wonderfully in Json.NET.

Comment: I chose to use RestSharp as it allows me to handle the creation and execution of HTTP requests and the deserialisation of the response in one place. For example: `var response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);`. It meets my requirements for the moment in a nice, succint manner. What sort of issues did you run into? Thanks.

Comment: @AdamJames sorry if I did not explain myself correctly. I use RESTSharp as well to make the call, but once I get the response I use Json.NET to work with the JSON response I received. I kept running into exceptions deserializing the response on seemingly proper JSON that was handled fine by Json.NET which is also more powerful and flexible. So in summary RESTSharp I found it to be my preferred library for making calls and then I used the other one for interpreting the response.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that - I have a Pluralsight subscription so I'll be sure to watch your course and keep your approach in mind.

Comment: Hope it helps you. It certainly did for me when I used both libraries together.